# SORACOM Air の SIM の名前を一括で変更したい

Tags: soracom

SORACOM Air の SIM には名前を付けて管理することができますが、Web のコンソールで1つずつ変更していくのが手間です。
CSV をインポートするなど、一括で変更する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SORACOM では、SDK が提供されており、これを利用すると比較的容易にインポート、エクスポートが可能です。
以下は、CSVではなく、タブ区切りのサンプルです。

#### 前提

SORACOM SDK for Ruby と、jq コマンドがインストールされている事

#### エクスポート

```
~/work/simtag$ cat get_sim_name.sh
#!/bin/bash
soracom sim list | jq -r '.[] | .imsi+"  "+.tags.name'

~/work/simtag$ ./get_sim_name.sh > sim_tag.tsv
```

sim_tag.tsv が出力されます。

#### インポート

```
~/work/simtag$ cat set_sim_name.sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\t'
while read LINE; do
    tsv=($(echo "$LINE"))
    soracom sim update_tags --imsi ${tsv[0]} --tags=name:"${tsv[1]}"
done
~/work/simtag$ ./set_sim_name.sh < sim_tag.tsv
```

sim_tag.tsv からインポート(一括更新)されます。